# How can i optimize this below program?

Tags: c++, sorting, data-structures, implementation, array-algorithms

You are given an array A of length N. For any given integer X, you need to find an integer Z strictly greater than X such that Z is not present in the array A. You need to minimize the value of Z.

INPUT:

First line : Two space seperated integers N and Q denoting the number of elements in array A and the
number of queries respectively

Second line: N space seperated integers denoting the array elements

Next Q lines: Each line consists of an integer X

OUTPUT:
Print Q lines, each line denoting the answer to the corresponding query.

Sample Input:

```
5 2
2 7 5 9 15
3
9
```

Sample output:

```
4
10
```

Source - https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/sorting/quick-sort/practice-problems/algorithm/yet-to-keep-6f89250c/description/

My solution-

```
int main()
{
    ll n,q;
    cin>>n>>q;
    map<ll,bool>mp;
    for(ll i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        ll x;
        cin>>x;
        mp[x]=true;
    }
    while(q--)
    {
        ll x;
        cin>>x;
        x++;
        while(mp[x])
        {
            x++;
        }
        cout<<x<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Step zero would be, building the code with compiler optimizations enabled.

Comment: you suppose/hope all inputs are valid, better to check they are

Comment: Hint: `lower_bound` is a good starting point for checking values

Comment: `std::map<T, bool>` with only `true` values might be replaced by `std::set<T>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your complexity by query is `O(n)*(Z-X)`,

you might already reduce to `O(n)+(Z-X)` with:

```
ll x;
std::cin >> x;
x++;
auto it = mp.find(x);
if (it != mp.end()) {
    while (it != mp.end() && it->first == x) {
        ++it;
        ++x;
    }
}
std::cout << x << std::endl;
```

But I think that building intervals in pre-processing would allow even better performance (`O(log(Intervals))`).

Comment: Hey @Jarod42 can you please elaborate more on this. I am getting only 3 test cases passed out of 30 test cases. So please provide some more explanation on how to reduce time complexity in this.

Comment: I meant if numbers are 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 40, you might create simple intervals `[1;10] [40;40]` to reduce complexity of query.